# Asp.net C# How to send file and message to client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, httpresponse

1- I would like to send a .zip folder with password to client

and

2- send the password to the bottom of the user's page.

and

3- send a warning to raise security awareness to user

In my HttpResponse, I can either send the file OR send the popup message and the password.

Thanks in advance.

```
// Creating zip file with password encryption.
string password = Membership.GeneratePassword(64, 10);
FastZip zip = new FastZip();
zip.EntryEncryptionMethod = ZipEncryptionMethod.AES256;
zip.Password = password;
zip.CreateZip(folderPath + ".zip", folderPath, true, "");

// Sending file to user.
Response.ContentType = "Application/zip";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + folderName);
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Temp/" + folderName));

// Sending password and warning to user (popup).
Response.Write("<script>alert('Avertissement : S’il vous plaît, éviter de conserver les documents confidentiels sur votre poste afin d’éviter la compromission d’informations identifiables personnels (PII) d\\'employés.');</script>");

// Send password to user page (on html page).
litMsgWm.Text = "Utiliser le mot de passe: " + password + " <br> et le logiciel '7Zip' pour décrypter le fichier zip envoyé à votre navigateur.";
```

What I want to send:

1- the password
[image]

2- the security awareness warning
[image]

3- the zip file

[image]

I tried:

Sending the file and the password through the same http response. I dont know if we can send 2 Http responses one after the other, or just one at the time? Ideally, I would like to send two separate Http responses to the client. I tried it but it doesn't work. (I'm not the best with Http)

Comment: You can only send a file OR html/ajax to the client at one time from the same response. Not both. You could open the url with the zip with javascript and then it will download in a separate response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used OnClientClick() which is called first, on the client browser, to show the message. Then I used OnClick() to launch the file download, on the server.

```
<asp:Button id="btnDownload" Text="Télécharger" Title="Télécharger le fichier sélectionné" CssClass="btn_cover" OnClientClick="ShowSecAwarenessMessage();" OnClick="Download_Click" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do [not post code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy code and paste here as  code; there is a very nice `formatting aid for code` with CTRL-K or using {}.